# threading and pyqt windows

Tags: python, pyqt, python-multithreading, pyside

I'm new using the threading library on python, and i work with pyQT. I am trying to open another window or another application in a threading class. But it doesen't work.
I have a main class which call my thread object and show my main windows, but when i run the application i have only the windows on my threading class which is showed, whereas i want that the two windows of the two apllications are runing in the same time?
I have one file with my main class which show my main windows :

`

```
 class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

 def __init__(self):
     super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
     self.setupUi(self)`

 if __name__ == '__main__': # Precise that's the main class.

    #thread object
    m = ThreadModel() 
    m.start()

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # main window
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()`
```

and one file with my threading class, which call my second windows in a new QApplication :

`

```
class ThreadModel(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self):
    
  threading.Thread.__init__(self)`

def run(self):


    application = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QWidget()

    widget.resize(250, 250)
    widget.setWindowTitle("test")
    widget.show()

    application.exec_()`
```

When i run my main class without run the threading class my main class works fine and show the main windows. But when i add the threading class i have only my window from threading class which is displayed. If you have a way to call a window from a threading class it can be hlep me a lot.
Thanks to your attention.

Comment: Only one QApplication instance should always exist and run its event loop, not even in another thread. Why are you trying to use threading?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your clarification, in fact the code I'm trying to put in place is more complex than the one I posted, but I wanted to simplify the question as much as possible. In reality in my thread class I have a pynput function (another python library), allowing me to listen to the keyboard shortcuts in the background of my application, I would have liked to open a window, when I execute this shortcut, it is why I needed to show a window from my thread.

Comment: UI elements are not thread safe, you cannot directly access (nor create them) in external threads. Put the pynput listener in a QThread subclass and create a custom signal to be emitted when the user triggers the shortcut, then connect that signal to a function that opens the window. Do some research as there are already dozens of similar posts, also related to pynput.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help i will search on this side :)